# Creating random Triangles in Java

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, colors, shapes

I need to create a program that generates five random triangles, all filled with a random color. The triangles must also be redrawn as the window is resized. The problem is the triangles aren't showing up at all, I just get a gray box. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, like a missing import or a line in the wrong place, but I've tried adjusting the code numerous times to no avail. Do I have the arrays for the drawPolygon all wrong? I don't know - I really need some help here.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

 class RandomTriangles extends JPanel {
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         float strokeThickness = 2.0f;

        BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(strokeThickness,
                BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
        g2d.setStroke(stroke);

        Random randGen = new Random();
        int curHeight = this.getHeight();
        int curWidth = this.getWidth();

        int [] x = new int [3];
        int [] y = new int [3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            x[i] = randGen(curWidth);
            y[i] = randGen(curHeight);
        }

        for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++){
            g2d.fillPolygon(x, y, 3);
            g2d.setColor(new Color(randGen.nextInt(256),      randGen.nextInt(256), randGen.nextInt(256)));
        }

    }

    private int randGen(int curWidth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Triangles {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Triangles();
    }

        Triangles() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Triangles");

        frame.add(new RandomTriangles());

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: so is there an error ? is the output different than the expected output? what exactly is the problem? and your randGen() method is not randomly generating anything, it is just returning 0 every time

Comment: Time to debug your program. Have you stepped through this with a debugger, or at least added a bunch of print statements, to figure out when the program's execution differs from your expectations? What are the values of every variable when that happens? Why are they that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create a Random object, which is good!

```
    Random randGen = new Random();
```

But you never use it. Instead, you call randGen, a fuction you've defined

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        x[i] = randGen(curWidth);
        y[i] = randGen(curHeight);
    }
```

But randGen is defined to always return 0! You should erase that method, and in your loop call

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        x[i] = randGen.nextInt(curWidth);
        y[i] = randGen.nextInt(curHeight);
    }
```

Comment: You should also mention that `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {...}` should be part of `for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {..}`.

Comment: I could kiss you right now ControlAltDel and you Pshemo. You both just saved my bacon and made my day. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Adam, you should NOT be generating the random triangles in the paintComponent() method. Whenever you resize the frame the paintComponent() method will be called again and your triangles will randomly be regenerated, which as a user I would find annoying. Instead you should generate triangles when you create the class. Also, you should override `paintComponent(...)` NOT paint(...).

Comment: Also you should create a class to contain the triangles and the color so they can be repainted properly. Check out the `CororedRectangle` class found in the `DrawOnComponent.java` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach.